# very elementary question about bases on the real line

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathcal{U} = \{ (-\infty,a) : a \in \mathbb{R} \} $. I want to show $\mathcal{U}$ is a basis for a topology on the real line.

#### Attempt

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Choose $I = (-\infty, x+1)$. Then $x \in I \subset \mathbb{R}$.

Now, take $I_1 = ( -\infty,a) $ and $I_2 = ( -\infty, b ) $ with $x \in I_1 \cap I_2 $. I want to find $I_3$ such that $ x \in I_3 \subset I_1 \cap I_2$. wlog we can assume $a > b$. Then, can we choose just $I_3 = I_2 $ ?

Def of Basis:

Let $X$ be a set. a basis for a toplogy of $X$ is a collection $\mathscr{B}$ of subsets of  $X$ such that

1. for each $x \in X$, there is $B \in \mathscr{B}$ such that $x \in B \subset X$.
2. If $B_1,B_2 \in \mathscr{B}$ with $x \in B_1 \cap B_2 $ then there is $B_3 \in \mathscr{B}$ such that $ x \in B_3 \subset B_1 \cap B_2 $.

Comment: Yes, you can take $I_3=I_2$. More generally, $$(\leftarrow,a)\cap(\leftarrow,b)=(\leftarrow,\min\{a,b\})\;.$$

Comment: I see. So, I don't need to assume $a > b$. I can just choose my $I_3 = ( - \infty , \min\{a, b \} - 1 ) $ ?

Comment: It's actually not just the basis for a topology, it's an entire topology. It's closed under arbitrary union and intersection (if you include the empty set and the whole line).

Comment: @FromCuba: You don’t want that $-1$: it might exclude the point $x$. Just use $(\leftarrow,\min\{a,b\})$ itself.

Comment: @Matt: Not quite: it’s missing $\varnothing$ and $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Thanks prof. Brian. If you want, write your comment as an answer so that I can accept your answer. Thanks very much again for your time.